# How to use temp variable instead of absolute column value in data.forEach function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, d3.js

i am stuck at this part. I wish to use a temp variable instead of the absolute column value inside the csv. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
d3.csv("barchart-data.csv", function (data) {
    var valueKey = data.columns; // get all the column names in the csv
    var obj={};
    var temp = 0;

    // valueKey[6]-[9] Column G-J in csv
    for (var i=6; i<=9; i++){
      console.log(valueKey[i]) // Enabled, Operating System Version, Operating System, Country
      temp = valueKey[i]
      data.forEach(function(d){ // number of rows in the csv
        obj[d.temp] = [d.temp] // dont work
        obj[d.Enabled] = [d.Enabled] // work
        console.log([d.temp])
      })
    }

  })
```

Comment: What D3 version?

Comment: Well, when asking a question on SO it's a good idea sticking around for some minutes, just to see the comments. Anyway, you have no property named `temp`, so it should be `obj[d[temp]]`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado D3v4

Comment: @GerardoFurtado ur suggestion works! Thanks,  appreciated!